# Extra characters added to CSV file when using To_CSV Function

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataframe that I'm exporting to a CSV file using to_csv. It exports fine, but noticed a problem trying to upload the CSV to BigQuery - Google gave a special characters error. While Control F searching for different characters, I found that there's a " * " in every single field of the sheet (see photo), however you don't see the * in formula bar when selecting one.

When I attempt to use Control F and replace the * with a blank, it deletes all of data on the sheet.

Tried opening the csv in a text editor and it finds no abnormal figures.

Seen lots of posts about this problem, but no resolution.

Problem background:
I have a folder of XML files containing tax returns for nonprofits downloaded from the IRS website. End objective: put all of the data from the XML files into a dataframe, export to a CSV, and upload to BigQuery.

Creating a list of all the elements from a sample file

```
tree = ET.parse('/content/drive/MyDrive/XML Files/Scraped/202030509349200503_public.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
list_of_elements = []
for element in root.iter():
   list_of_elements.append(element.tag)
```

Looping through each XML file, saving the values for each element to a list, then saving that list to a master list (xml_values)

```
xml_values = []
for filename in os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/XML Files/Scraped'):
  if filename.endswith('.xml'):
    tree=ET.parse('/content/drive/MyDrive/XML Files/Scraped/'+filename)
    root=tree.getroot()
    values=[]
    for element in root.iter():
      values.append(element.text)
  xml_values.append(values)
```

Assigning the list of lists as values to a DF and assigning the list of attributes as column titles

```
xml_data=pd.DataFrame(xml_values)
xml_data.columns=list_of_elements
```

Added another photo of sample data.
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxW1G.png)
[image: Screenshot of excel]

[image: Screenshot of Text Editor]

Comment: @BigBen I gotcha. I went through and added some background context, my code to create the dataframe, and sample output of the df.

Comment: `Google gave a special characters error.` What's the exact text of this error?

Comment: Don't open your csv file in excel and do analysis on its contents. All you'll end up with is analysis on excel's tortured interpretation of your csv file. Consider a proper editor like Notepad++ where you can toggle on "Show all characters" and whatnot. What is the error you are getting from bigquery? Does it share any information about the special character that was found?

Comment: @NickODell - BQ error: Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 2937. Error: Missing close quote character (").

Comment: That error usually will pop if there is a double quote contained within the string that is itself enclosed in double quotes, but is either improperly escaped, or the escape character hasn't been set properly in the config of the platform/code that is reading the CSV. Your data likely looks like `"This is some \"data\""` where the escape character is a backslash. Like you'll need to tell bigquery that  a backslash is the escape character for the csv file.

Comment: If you print out the data starting at offset 2937, is there anything strange about it? Example of how to do this: `f=open('VetNPTaxData.csv', 'rt');f.seek(2937);print(f.read(200))`

Comment: @JNevill I'm not familiar with BQ at all, just have to get a doc in there for an assignment. Would this be done by modifying the schema?

Comment: @Brock I'm not familiar with it either, but reading through the documentation and forums, it looks like it's not very malleable with CSVS. I don't see a `--` flag for escape character (which is crazy nonsense I'm convinced I just haven't dug far enough). If that proves to be true, then perhaps consider outputting your data in JSON so you don't have to deal with the pain-in-the-butt oddities of CSV flat files.